# What is wrong with my bilinear interpolation algorithm?

Tags: php, algorithm, image-processing, gd, bilinear-interpolation

I am using PHP to test out my bilinear algorithm. The code is un-optimized for clarity.

Here is what the code below is doing:

1. Plot the original pixels from the 2x2 image to the 10x10 destination
   image. These will leave blank pixels.

Note: The images here are resized from 10x10 to 100x100 for better viewing.

[image: resized]

2. Interpolate the row of pixels.

[image]

3. Interpolate the remaining pixels going from left to right, top to bottom using the row of pixels in step 2:

[image]

However, it does not match the result I get in Photoshop using bilinear resampling:

[image]

Full source code:

```
<?php
$image1 = imagecreatefrompng( 'test.png' );

$w1 = imagesx( $image1 );
$h1 = imagesy( $image1 );

$w2 = 10;
$h2 = 10;
$image2 = imagecreatetruecolor( $w2, $h2 );

imagefill($image2, 0, 0, imagecolorallocate($image2, 0x4c, 0x4c, 0x8e)); // added bg for pixels to stand-out

function lerp($v0, $v1, $t) {
    return $v0 + $t*($v1-$v0);
}

function getPixel($image, $x, $y){
    $rgb = imagecolorat( $image, $x, $y );
    $r     = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
    $g     = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
    $b     = $rgb & 0xFF;
    return array($r,$g,$b);
}

$maxY1 = $h1 - 1;
$maxX1 = $w1 - 1;
$maxY2 = $h2 - 1;
$maxX2 = $w2 - 1;

// plot original pixels from source to destination
for($y = 0; $y <= $maxY1; $y++) { // loop thru src height

    $newY = floor(($y/$maxY1) * $maxY2);

    for ($x = 0; $x <= $maxX1; $x++) { // loop thru src width

        $newX = floor(($x/$maxX1) * $maxX2);
        $rgb = imagecolorat( $image1, $x, $y );
        $r1     = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $g1     = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $b1     = $rgb & 0xFF;

        imagesetpixel( $image2, $newX, $newY, imagecolorallocate( $image2, $r1, $g1, $b1 ) );

    }
}
imagepng( $image2, 'out1.png' );

// interpolate pixels from pixel[1,0] to pixel[8,0]
$y = 0;
$rgb = imagecolorat( $image2, 0, $y );
$r0     = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
$g0     = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
$b0     = $rgb & 0xFF;

$rgb = imagecolorat( $image2, 9, $y );
$r1     = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
$g1     = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
$b1     = $rgb & 0xFF;
for($x=1; $x <= 8; $x++){
    $t = $x / 9;
    $r = lerp($r0, $r1, $t);
    $g = lerp($g0, $g1, $t);
    $b = lerp($b0, $b1, $t);
    imagesetpixel( $image2, $x, $y, imagecolorallocate( $image2, $r, $g, $b ) );
}
imagepng( $image2, 'out2.png' );

// interpolate pixels from pixel[1,9] to pixel[8,9]
$y = 9;
$rgb = imagecolorat( $image2, 0, $y );
$r0     = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
$g0     = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
$b0     = $rgb & 0xFF;

$rgb = imagecolorat( $image2, 9, $y );
$r1     = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
$g1     = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
$b1     = $rgb & 0xFF;

for($x=1; $x <= 8; $x++){
    $t = $x / 9;
    $r = lerp($r0, $r1, $t);
    $g = lerp($g0, $g1, $t);
    $b = lerp($b0, $b1, $t);
    imagesetpixel( $image2, $x, $y, imagecolorallocate( $image2, $r, $g, $b ) );
}
imagepng( $image2, 'out3.png' );

// interpolate remaining pixels
for($x=0; $x <= 9; $x++){
    $rgb = imagecolorat( $image2, $x, 0 );
    $r0     = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
    $g0     = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
    $b0     = $rgb & 0xFF;

    $rgb = imagecolorat( $image2, $x, 9 );
    $r1     = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
    $g1     = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
    $b1     = $rgb & 0xFF;
    for($y = 1; $y <= 8; $y++){
        $t = $y / 9;
        $r = lerp($r0, $r1, $t);
        $g = lerp($g0, $g1, $t);
        $b = lerp($b0, $b1, $t);
        imagesetpixel( $image2, $x, $y, imagecolorallocate( $image2, $r, $g, $b ) );
    }
}
imagepng( $image2, 'out4.png' );

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng( $image2);
imagedestroy( $image1 );
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your result looks perfect. That of Photoshop isn't bilinear. Presumably bicubic ?

Comment: yours is better. it's photoshop that's wrong in this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photoshop is correct. In your version the original 4 pixel values end up in the extreme corners of the new image but in the correct bilinear interpolation they end up in the centers of 4 quadrants of the new image. There is no information beyond the edge of the original image so photoshop does constant extrapolation at the edge:

2x2:

[image]

10x10 before interpolation:

[image]

If you started with a 3x3 image instead of 2x2, your method would cause the original edge pixels to have a diminished contribution to the final image relative to the center pixels, biasing the result.

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the PS result closely, you will notice that before the interpolation corner pixels have been resized 9-fold (they take up 3x3 in the corners of the image). This is obviously done to get a more sharp edges, for better or worse.

If you add logic for generating an intermediate image before the interpolation:

[image: intermediate image]

...and modify your interpolation algorythm to omit the corner pixel blocks, then you should get the same result.